# Applet to adjust system volume

Tags: java, audio, applet, volume

I need to create an applet to adjust windows sound, like mute, increase and decrease volume etc. Is there any API for this? `sndvol32.exe` opens the volume control. But I can't  place it in my web page. So please help me to write an applet.

Comment: Why on would anyone want to use an embedded applet to adjust the system sound volume?

Comment: Sir I launch internet explorer in kiosk mode so task bar will not appear.

Answer (score 1):

If this can be done in a digitally signed applet, it can be done in a `JFrame` or from the command line, both of which will be easier to test.  If you can get it to work in either of the latter two, put that code in a digitally signed applet (then convince the user to accept the digitally signed code that replicates functionality that is already in their Windows OS).

Comment: Thank you sir!.. What is the command to increase or decrease system volume?